# Слоты и сигналы Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть виджет, назовем его Link, и окно MainWindow. Нужно сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на виджет Link выполнялось какое-то действие из MainWindow, например отрисовка еще одного виджета.
Сделал обработку нажатия на виджет, то есть при нажатии на Link в нем вызывается слот, но как вызвать слот или отправить сигнал в MainWindow не могу понять, ведь они друг о друге ничего не знают и передать MainWindow в конструктор Link'y никак не получится, да и не логично это.
На самом деле структура намного сложнее и привести примеры кода не получится, т.к. его слишком много, но суть проблемы я описал

Answer (score 7):

Если я вас правильно понял, вопрос заключается в том, как послать сигнал от одного виждета другому. Это делается примерно так:

В классе `Link` объявим сигнал `clicked` и отправим его в методе `foo`

```
class Link : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
//...
signals:
    void clicked();
public:
    void foo(){
        emit clicked();
    }
};
```

В классе `MainWindow` объявим слот `doSmth`:

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void doSmth(){
         //...
    }
};
```

Соединим:

```
Link *link = new Link;
MainWindow *mainWindow = new MainWindow;
connect(link, SIGNAL(clicked()),  mainWindow, SLOT(doSmth()));
```

Или если вы используете новый синтаксис:

```
connect(link, &Link::clicked,  mainWindow, &MainWindow::doSmth);
```

Теперь при вызове метода `foo` у `link` будет выполнен слот `doSmth` у `mainWindow`